# Is there any state wise and quarterly downloadable US economic data apart from GDP?

Tags: data-request, usa, data.gov, economics

I am looking for some downloadable US economic `dataset`, apart from GDP data, which has data `state wise` and `quarterly`. I went through [BLS website](http://www.bls.gov/data/) but either couldn't find any relevant data which has state wise and quarterly information or couldn't find a way to download those.

Is anyone aware of any such economic `dataset` that I can download?

Comment: How about the Economic Census? http://www.census.gov/econ/isp/

Comment: bea.gov/regional/downloadzip.cfm (but only annual)

Answer (score 4):

Quandl has a dataset from the [Bureau of Economic Analysis](https://www.quandl.com/data/BEA/documentation/about) that might be helpful for you. It has many economic metrics at the state level.

Quandl is a great resource for datasets like this.

Answer (score 2):

Try the Quarterly Census of Employment and Wages (QCEW). I work for this part of BLS.

QCEW provides employment and wage data by industry at the county, MSA, State, and national levels.  Go to http://www.bls.gov/cew/opendata.htm
to access the open data version of the dataset.  Available for 2012-forward, QCEW open data is a csv-based static API.

We built it with users like you in mind.  We are using it as the input for all our future QCEW data front ends, so it has to be great!

For data prior to 2012, (back to 1975 at some levels of aggregation), see the flat files available at http://www.bls.gov/cew/datatoc.htm Many of the resources at this location are zip archives of csv files.